# Export Sheets as CSV to Worbook path

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I created an `.xlam` add-in that exports any Excel file's `Worksheet`'s as separate `CSV` files and saves them to the same `path` as the `Workbook`.

However I run into an error attempting to save the files to the same destination as the open `Workbook` using `ActiveWorkbook` instead of `ThisWorkbook` on this line:

`xcsvFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & xWs.Name & ".csv"`

`ThisWorkbook` runs without error but saves the files in the add-ins folder (`C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns`), and not the path where the original Workbook was opened.

```
Sub ExportSheetsToCSV()
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xcsvFile As String
For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    'Delete the first and last rows to delimit properly'
    xWs.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).EntireRow.Delete
    xWs.Range("1:1").Delete
    xWs.Copy
    'Find the path of where you opened the file and save the CSV's there'
    xcsvFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & xWs.Name & ".csv"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xcsvFile, _
                                      FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next
'Closes the original workbook without saving the changes'
ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
Application.Quit
```

End Sub

Comment: That's because the ThisWorkbook path is for the .xlsm file, not the file you're running the macro against.

You should capture the path to the active workbook in a variable and use this to set your save path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given music2myear's comment, I was able to solve the issue by first finding the Workbook path and using it as a variable.

```
    Sub ExportSheetsToCSV()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xcsvFile As String
    Dim folderPath As String
    folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Delete the first and last rows to delimit properly'
        xWs.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).EntireRow.Delete
        xWs.Range("1:1").Delete
        xWs.Copy
        'Find the path of where you opened the file and save the CSV's there'
        xcsvFile = folderPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".csv"
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xcsvFile, _
                                          FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Next
    'Closes the original workbook without saving the changes'
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    Application.Quit

End Sub
```